# Tkinter python 3.7 AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: sqlite, tkinter, python-3.7, attributeerror

I'm writing an inventory database program. I'm a novice so I'm sure I have something wrong.

```py
def select_item():
    #Create a Database or Connect to one
    conn = sqlite3.connect('inventory.db')
    #Create Cursor
    c = conn.cursor()

    a = id_select.get()

    c.execute("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE oid = " + a)
    records = c.fetchall()

    for record in records:
        Item_editor.insert(0, record[0])
        Quantity_editor.insert(0, record[1])
        Asset_tag_editor.insert(0, record[2])
        Notes_editor.insert(0, record[3])

#Entry Fields
id_select = Entry(editor, width=30)
id_select.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=(20, 0))
Item_editor = Entry(editor, width=30)
Item_editor.grid(row=2, column=1)
Quantity_editor = Entry(editor, width=30)
Quantity_editor.grid(row=3, column=1)
Asset_tag_editor = Entry(editor, width=30)
Asset_tag_editor.grid(row=4, column=1)
Notes_editor = Entry(editor, width=30)
Notes_editor.grid(row=5, column=1)

#Button Time!
id_select = Button(editor, text="Select Item", command=select_item)
id_select.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10, padx=10, ipadx=100)
```

I did not initially have a function, but realized that I would need one for the command in the button. The error points to my variable **a = id_select.get()**, but I'm pretty sure that I have my entry fields added properly.

Comment: emmm....`id_select` finally is a ``button`` widget.You shouldn't use the same two variables name.

Comment: I see that now I totally missed it when I was reviewing my code for errors. Tired eyes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is from the fact that id_select is a button. You initially had 
`id_select = Entry(editor, width=30)` which has .get(), but you replaced `id_select` in `id_select = Button(editor, text="Select Item", command=select_item)` which does not have one. You should name your button something else.

Comment: I completely missed it. Thanks!