# tkinter: AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, widget, openfiledialog

I'm trying to write a small GUI with tkinter where the user can select a folder and then this folder gets proccessed.

I created a button with a command to select a folder using the `filedialog.askdirectory` function from tkinter. Now I want to pass the path to a variable which I can use in an other function.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

# %% define the GUI Class
class OCTExportGUI():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master=master
        self.master.title("OCT - RAW Export")
        self.pathToFolder = None
        self.master['padx'] = 5
        self.master['pady'] = 5

# %% define GUI Widgets here
        self.pickFolderBtn = tk.Button(master, text="Chose Folder", width=10,
                                       command = self.folderPicker)
        self.pickFolderBtn.grid(row=10, column=0)
        

        self.executeBtn = tk.Button(master, text="Execute", width=10,
                                    command = self.executeExport)
        self.executeBtn.grid(row=20, column=0)
            
# %% Functions for GUI 
    def folderPicker(self):
        filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir = "/",title = "Select Folder Containing Your OCT Files")
        self.pathToFolder=self.pickFolderBtn.get()
        self.master.destroy
 
    def executeExport(self):
        print("execute")
        self.master.destroy
        
# %% Define Main loop end extract input variables
master = tk.Tk()
OEG=OCTExportGUI(master)
master.mainloop()

x = OEG.pathToFolder
```

Unfortunately I get the following error.

```
  File "C:\Users\tmc\Desktop\OCT_Export\Widget.py", line 43, in folderPicker
    self.pathToFolder=self.pickFolderBtn.get()
AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'get'
```

it seems like that a tkinter button has no attribute get(). How is the propper way to get the path from the function `folderPicker()`?

Best TMC

a similiar question was asked here: [Tkinter python 3.7 AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'get'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60656947/tkinter-python-3-7-attributeerror-button-object-has-no-attribute-get) but the answer does obviously not apply to my case.

Comment: You should use `self.pathToFolder = filedialog.askdirectory(...)`.

Comment: you can do something like `self.path = filedialog.askdirectory(...)` because`filedialog.askdirectory()` returns the path of the file, you can check with `print(filedialog.askdirectory(...))`

Comment: thank you both: ```self.path = ``` did the trick. I just omitted the ```self.pathToFolder=self.pickFolderBtn.get()``` and replaced it with ```self.pathToFolder=self.path```. I'm quite sure I had a version with ```self.pathToFolder= filedialog.askdirectory``` but I got stuck with the ```get()``` Problem.

Comment: `self.path = filedialog.askdirectory()` followed by `self.pathToFolder = self.path` is the same as `self.pathToFolder = filedialog.askdirectory()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply define self.pathToFolder as a string.

```
def folderPicker(self):
        self.pathToFolder = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir = "/",title = "Select Folder Containing Your OCT Files")
```